# Can an AFSP training request be renewed when the current one has not yet expired?

Tags: flight-training, usa, tsa

My Alien Flight Student Program (AFSP) training request expires in about two months, so the aviation school I'm learning with asked me to just go ahead and create a new training request so there's no wait time between my current request expiration date and whenever the new one would come in.

However, I cannot find an option to create one when the current one is active looks like.

Can you apply for a new training request before the current one expires? If so, how many days before?